# how to upload files from bytes into gcp with pyton3

Tags: python

I need to make a code that list / files from s3 bucket and upload in a gcp bucket

```
def download_from_s3():
    files = s3_client.list_objects_v2(
    Bucket=bucket_name,
    Prefix=folder
    )

    output = []
    for content in files.get('Contents', []):
        object_key = content['Key']
        report_type = parse_type(object_key)
        if report_type == "":
            continue
                    
        file = s3_client.get_object(
            Bucket=bucket_name,
            Key=object_key
        )

        object_body = file['Body'].read()
        output.append({
            "Key": os.path.basename(object_key),
            "Type": parse_type(object_key),
            "File": object_body,
        })

    return output
```

I found an example code from gcp, but the sending is through a file and I already have an array of bytes and not the files, is it possible to send without passing the file path, but the bytes?

```html
def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file, destination_blob_name):
    """Uploads a file to the bucket."""
    # The ID of your GCS bucket
    # bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
    # The path to your file to upload
    # source_file_name = "local/path/to/file"
    # The ID of your GCS object
    # destination_blob_name = "storage-object-name"

    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

    # Optional: set a generation-match precondition to avoid potential race conditions
    # and data corruptions. The request to upload is aborted if the object's
    # generation number does not match your precondition. For a destination
    # object that does not yet exist, set the if_generation_match precondition to 0.
    # If the destination object already exists in your bucket, set instead a
    # generation-match precondition using its generation number.
    generation_match_precondition = 0

    blob(source_file, if_generation_match=generation_match_precondition)

    print(
        f"File {source_file} uploaded to {destination_blob_name}."
    )

def send_from_s3_to_gcp(s3_files):
    for content in s3_files:
        upload_blob(
            bucket_name=gcp_bucket_name,
            source_file=content["File"],
            destination_blob_name=content["Type"]+content["Key"],
        )

s3_client = build_session(role_arn, role_arn_name).client('s3')

output = download_from_s3()
send_from_s3_to_gcp(output)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`blob.upload_from_string`](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/latest/google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob#google_cloud_storage_blob_Blob_upload_from_string), passing it your `bytes` object as `data`.

Comment: can u help me with this code?